# SSRS Reporting Services calculating 2 sums if parameter is true

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a simple income and covers served per day report, I need to calculate the variance % difference between this years income and last years income, but excluding any sites that opened this year.

I have the following expression however the results it returns are way out from what I am expecting:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!New_Site.Value=False And  Fields!netSalesLY.Value<>0,CDbl(Fields!netSalesTY.Value/Fields!netSalesLY.Value),CDbl(0)))
```

New_Site is a Boolean parameter to filter out new/old sites, and both netsalesTY and netsalesLY are integer values.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more info about your expected results vs the results you got?  Where are you putting this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're not referencing the New_Site parameter, you're referencing the New_Site field in your formula. If you wanted to reference the New_Site parameter, you would do it as

```
Parameters!New_Site.value
```

Not sure which you are really wanting to use.

Also, I may be misunderstanding what number you're trying to calculate, but if I understand you correctly, you're using the wrong formula. You're not using the percent difference formula, which will return the percent of this years sales related to last years sales, not a difference between the two. If what you want to know is the percent difference between the two years, it would be calculated as:

```
(Fields!netSalesTY.Value - Fields!netSalesLY.Value) / Fields!netSalesLY.Value
```

So if last year your netSales were $100,000 and this year they are $85,000, your current formula would return 85%, whereas the formula I just mentioned would return -15%, thus showing the decline in sales. So with the formula I gave you, a negative number would represent a decrease from last year to this year and a positive number would represent an increase from last year to this year.

Hope this helps!